# Android: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

Im using Android Support Library v7-AppCompat in my app, i have imported the v7-AppCompat as a library for my app and it works with the code the problem is when i try to apply the AppCompat theme to the app. I have included the modules and the library as well, but still the theme is not working. Even tried copying the themes.xml and theme-base.xml to the values folder but it only results in more errors.

Answer (score 0):

you are using this `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` instead use this `parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`.i guess they have typo in the docs file

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the compile Version of your app to the latest sdk you have installed ie 22 or 23 and it should work.